# Animate background-position from outside of element to inside

Tags: jquery, html, background, jquery-animate

I'm having issues animating a background image from OUTSIDE of an element to the INSIDE.

The following code works in Chrome as long as the image is always within the bounds of the element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.title').css({backgroundPosition: '100% 100px'}).animate({
          'background-position-x': '100%',
          'background-position-y': '50%'
        }, 1000, 'linear');
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.title {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6) url(https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo3w.png) no-repeat;
}
</style>

<div class="title"></div>​
```

...however, if the image starts outside of the elements bounds it jumps about and doesn't work as expected.

[HERE IS A JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YHg9n/)

The above code doesn't work at all in FF so I guess there must be some fundamental error with my code that I haven't spotted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is Firefox's willful ignorance of `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` -- you have to use `background-position` in your code instead, but you can't `animate()` on a grouped property like that. The only solution I can think of is to use two DIV elements stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Makes no difference. The image should start outside the bottom edge of the div.title and move up in to the centre of the div.